# Topic Coherence with Dictionary from Glove (gensim)

Tags: python, gensim

I'm trying to evaluate a home-made topic model. For this, I'm using the list of topics (represented by keywords), and want to use a `gensim.models.coherencemodel.CoherenceModel`, and call it on a corpus, which is a list of strings (each one being a document).
The `CoherenceModel` requires a `Dictionary`, but I don't understand what this corresponds to, and how I can get it.
I'm using the `TfidfVectorizer` from `sklearn` to vectorize the text, and `glove` embeddings from `gensim` to compute similarities within my model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs, a `Dictionary` can be created from a corpus where the corpus is a `list of lists of str`. This same corpus should be passed in the `text` argument of the `CoherenceModel`.